# Qml get resolved font family

Tags: qt, qml

There is a way to get Font family that was resolved to in Qml
https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-text.html#fontInfo.family-prop

However this property is available only from Qt5.9, how can we get this info for older versions (Qt 5.4 to be precise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this is done in Qt 5.9 and later is via embedding a [`QFontInfo`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontinfo.html) in the `Text` object and returning a JS object to the QML with all relevant fields of the `QFontInfo` as keys of the object.

How I would add this in previous version is by creating a new `QObject` class with a `Q_INVOKABLE QVariantMap fontInfo(const QFont& font)`.

This function would construct a `QFontInfo` from the font, and fill the `QVariantMap` with the relevant info you need.

Register it to be able to use it in QML with `qmlRegisterSingletonType()`.

And then you could use it like that in QML :

```
Text {
    property var fontInfo: FontUtils.fontInfo(font)
}
```